# Предотвращение переноса при выводе pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x, dataframe

Версия Python 2.7.14, необходимо вывести таблицу, но она не помещается в строчку и выходит что половину таблицы он переносит на новую строку, как это можно избежать?
Слышал что это можно вроде сделал с помощью `pytablewriter` попробовал, может не правильно делал но он выводит только первую строку и тоже переводит на новую строку.
P.S. Естественно пробовал после print`писать`,` не помогло

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = et.parse("book.xml")
    dfcols = ['author', 'name', 'publich', 'year','page']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
        author=node.find('author')
        name = node.find('name')
        publich = node.find('publich')
        year = node.find('year')
        page = node.find('page')

        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([getvalueofnode(author), getvalueofnode(name), getvalueofnode(publich),
                       getvalueofnode(year),getvalueofnode(page)], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)

    print df_xml

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вопрос о том как сделать так чтобы Pandas не переносил столбцы DataFrame'a при печати на экран:

```
In [87]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 15))

In [88]: df
Out[88]:
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        11        12  \
0  0.070819  0.332764  0.885132  0.491423  0.477713  0.068572  0.996516  0.249914  0.529250  0.928961  0.021879  0.716097  0.401637
1  0.944837  0.994282  0.182240  0.739485  0.848773  0.398100  0.456237  0.143301  0.818627  0.932551  0.767455  0.951487  0.928550
2  0.430288  0.841229  0.532633  0.329414  0.617338  0.358366  0.450393  0.777433  0.306454  0.111303  0.357694  0.007629  0.570589

         13        14
0  0.490648  0.997464
1  0.041154  0.841095
2  0.674984  0.098672
```

отключаем перенос:

```
In [89]: pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        11        12        13        14
0  0.070819  0.332764  0.885132  0.491423  0.477713  0.068572  0.996516  0.249914  0.529250  0.928961  0.021879  0.716097  0.401637  0.490648  0.997464
1  0.944837  0.994282  0.182240  0.739485  0.848773  0.398100  0.456237  0.143301  0.818627  0.932551  0.767455  0.951487  0.928550  0.041154  0.841095
2  0.430288  0.841229  0.532633  0.329414  0.617338  0.358366  0.450393  0.777433  0.306454  0.111303  0.357694  0.007629  0.570589  0.674984  0.098672
```

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, это делает **не питон**, а Ваш терминал/командная строка.
 Попробуйте в настройках командной строки(терминала) убрать пункт *перенос строки при превышении лимита символов*
Может этот пункт и не точно так называется, но суть, я надеюсь, Вы поняли.
 К сожалению, не могу Вам дать инструкции по командной строке(windows), но , надеюсь, я помог

Comment: если бы вы написали как конкретно это сделать, а так это просто очевидная рекомендация